# Какого рода слово "бра"?

Tags: морфология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какого рода слово "бра"? Я колеблюсь между женским и средним. А еще - изменяется это слово по падежам или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колебаться не надо - надо открыть орфографический словарь. Например, здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E1%F0%E0&all=x

Бра - среднего рода, несклоняемое (по падежам), неизменяемое (по числам).